# Fluentd Parsing

Tags: regex, fluentd

Hi i'm trying to parse single line log using fluentd. Here is log i'm trying to parse.

```
F2:4200000000000000,F3:000000,F4:000000060000,F6:000000000000,F7:000000000,F8..........etc
```

This will parse into like this:

```
{ "F2"   : "4200000000000000", "F3" : "000000", "F4"   : "000000060000" ............etc }
```

I tried to use regex but it's confusing and making me write multiple regexes for different keys and values. Is there any easier way to achieve this ?

**EDIT1:** Heya! I will make this more detailed. I'm currently tailing logs using fluentd to Elasticsearch+Kibana. Here is unparsed example log that fluentd sending to Elasticsearch:

```
21/09/02 16:36:09.927238: 1 frSMS:0:13995:#HTF4J::141:141:msg0210,00000000000000000,000000,000000,007232,00,#,F2:00000000000000000,F3:002000,F4:000000820000,F6:Random message and strings,F7:.......etc
```

- Elasticsearch recived message:

> {"message":"frSMS:0:13995:#HTF4J::141:141:msg0210,00000000000000000,000000,000000,007232,00,#,F2:00000000000000000,F3:002000,F4:000000820000,F6:Random
> digits and chars,F7:.......etc"}

This log has only message key so i can't index and create dashboard on only using whole message field. What am i trying to achieve is catch only useful fields, add key into it if it has no key and make indexing easier.

- Expected output:

> ```
> {"logdate" : "21/09/02 16:36:09.927238",
>      "source" : "frSMS",
>      "UID" : "#HTF4J",
>      "statuscode" : "msg0210",
>      "F2": "00000000000000000",
>      "F3": "randomchar314516",.....}
> ```

I used regex plugin to parse into this but it was too overwhelming and . Here is what i did so far:

```html
^(?<logDate>\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{6}\b)....(?<source>fr[A-Z]{3,4}|to[A-Z]{3,4}\b).(?<status>\d\b).(?<dummyfield>\d{5}\b).(?<HUID>.[A-Z]{5}\b)..(?<d1>\d{3}\b).(?<d2>\d{3}\b).(?<msgcode>msg\d{4}\b).(?<dummyfield1>\d{16}\b).(?<dummyfield2>\d{6}\b).(?<dummyfield3>\d{6,7}\b).(?<dummyfield4>\d{6}\b).(?<dummyfield5>\d{2}\b)...
```

Which results to :

> "logDate":    "21/09/02 16:36:09.205706",
> "source":     "toSMS" ,
> "status":     "0",
> "dummyfield": "13995" ,
> "UID" :       "#HTFAA" ,
> "d1"  :       "156" ,
> "d2"  :   "156" ,
> "msgcode" :   "msg0210",
> "dummyfield1" :"0000000000000000" ,
> "dummyfield2" :"002000",
> "dummyfield3"  :"2000000",
> "dummyfield4"  :"00",
> "dummyfield5" :"2000000" ,
> "dummyfield6" :"867202"

Which only applies to example log and has useless fields like field1, dummyfield, dummyfield1 etc.
Other logs has the useful values and keys(date,source,msgcode,UID,F1,F2 fields) like i showcased on expected output. Not useful fields are not static(they can be none, or has less|more digits and chars) so they trigger the pattern not matched error.

So the question is:

1. How do i capture useful fields that i mentioned using regex?
2. How do i capture F1,F2,F3...... fields that has different value
   patterns like char string mixed?

**PS**: I wraped the regex i wrote into html snippet so the <> capturing fields don't get deleted

Comment: What regex did you try? maybe this help you: `(\w+):([^,]+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Regex pattern to use:

```
(F[\d]+):([\d]+)
```

This pattern will catch all the `'F'` values with whatever digit that comes after - yes even if it's `F105` it still works. This whole `'F105'` will be stored as the first group in your regex match expression

The right part of the above pattern will catch the value of all the digits following `':'` up until any charachter that is not a digit. i.e. `',', 'F', etc..` and will store it as the second group in your regex match

## Use

Depending on your coding language you will have to access your regex `matches` variable with an iterator and extract `group 1` and `group 2` respectivly

## Python example:

```
import re

log = 'F2:4200000000000000,F3:000000,F4:000000060000,F6:000000000000,F7:000000000,F105:9726450'
pattern = '(F[\d]+):([\d]+)'
matches = re.finditer(pattern,log)
log_dict = {}
for match in matches:
    log_dict[match.group(1)] = match.group(2) 
print(log_dict)
```

## Output

```
{'F2': '4200000000000000', 'F3': '000000', 'F4': '000000060000', 'F6': '000000000000', 'F7': '000000000', 'F105': '9726450'}
```

Comment: There is no need to put \d in brackets, simply you can use: `(F\d+):(\d+)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the logdate will be static(in pattern wise) You can ignore useless values using ".+" regex and get collect the useful values by their patterns. So the regex will be like this :

> (?\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{6}\b).+(?fr[A-Z]{3,4}|to[A-Z]{3,4}).+(?#[A-Z0-9]{5}).+(?msg\d{4})

And output will be like:

> {"logdate" : "21/09/02 16:36:09.927238", "source" : "frSMS",
> "UID" : "#HTF4J","statuscode" : "msg0210"}

And I'm working on getting F2,F3,FN keys and values.